# Running eclipse task from command line

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, export

I have a bunch of J2EE applications built using eclipse, and I'd like to know if there's a way to automate the "export ear with sources" functionality in such way that I can program a task to run it every night.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found something for you. See [HeadlessEclipse](http://code.google.com/p/headlesseclipse/wiki/Documentation). It has an export-ears option. Be warned, the project says it is "officially dead". They did release versions, however.

Here's a [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic-portal/overview/wlp-headless-build-167758.html) that uses HeadlessEclipse.

I would probably put my effort towards converting your builds to Maven or ANT, but perhaps HeadlessEclipse is worth a quick shot.